# Error decodificando el token Illegal base64 character 22

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

Tengo un proyecto de Spring 2.7.10 con java 11 y java-jwt 4.3 y por alguna extraña razon genera el token pero al hacer la peticion get con el da error de validacion, pero no veo error alguno en el codigo.
Os dejo la configuracion y el token:
Este es el token que genera

```
{
    "jwttoken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY4MDEwMjYyNn0.Y_gpOM90tFdnpXQe8IWqyBk2t160LZFbklf1mc_yyt1e1EGTvJ-GtwUrwmY_83l0NQ-eKBQV4UpEi6oRRC9urA"
}
```

Este el que le paso a la peticion que veais que es el mismo:

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY4MDEwMjYyNn0.Y_gpOM90tFdnpXQe8IWqyBk2t160LZFbklf1mc_yyt1e1EGTvJ-GtwUrwmY_83l0NQ-eKBQV4UpEi6oRRC9urA
```

En el filtro le he puesto un print

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY4MDEwMjYyNn0.Y_gpOM90tFdnpXQe8IWqyBk2t160LZFbklf1mc_yyt1e1EGTvJ-GtwUrwmY_83l0NQ-eKBQV4UpEi6oRRC9urA
```

La clase token que peta en la linea

```
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
```

Esta es la clase

```
    @Component
public class JwtToken {

    private final String secret;

    public JwtToken(@Value("${jwt.secret}") String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, DecodedJWT::getSubject);
    }

    public Instant obtenerVencimientoDelToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, DecodedJWT::getExpiresAt).toInstant();
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<DecodedJWT, T> claimsResolver) {
        final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = decodeToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(decodedJWT);
    }

    private DecodedJWT decodeToken(String token) {
        try {
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(secret)).build();
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
            return jwt;
        } catch (JWTDecodeException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error decodificando el token", exception);
        }
    }

    private Boolean haExpiradoElToken(String token) {
        final Instant expiration = obtenerVencimientoDelToken(token);
        return expiration.isBefore(Instant.now());
    }

    public boolean esMedico(String token) {
        final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = decodeToken(token);
        final Map<String, Object> userMap = decodedJWT.getClaim("usuario").asMap();
        return userMap.get("licencia") != null;
    }

    public String generarToken(Logable user) {
        final Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        Medico medico = null;
        Paciente paciente = null;
        if (user instanceof Medico) {
            userMap.put("licencia", user.getIdentifier());
            medico = (Medico) user;
            userMap.put("nombre", medico.getNombre());
        } else if (user instanceof Paciente) {
            userMap.put("nss", user.getIdentifier());
            paciente = (Paciente) user;
            userMap.put("nombre", paciente.getNombre());
        }
        claims.put("usuario", new HashMap<>(userMap));
        return doGenerateToken(claims);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims) {
        final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(secret);
        final Date now = Date.from(Instant.now());
        final Date expirationTime = Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(30 * 60 * 60));
        Map<String, Object> usuarioClaims = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> originalUsuarioClaims = (Map<String, Object>) claims.get("usuario");
        usuarioClaims.putAll(originalUsuarioClaims);
        return JWT.create().withIssuedAt(now).withExpiresAt(expirationTime).withClaim("usuario", usuarioClaims)
                .sign(algorithm);
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, String expectedSubject) {
        try {
            final String identifier = obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(token);
            return (identifier.equals(expectedSubject) && !haExpiradoElToken(token));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al validar el token JWT", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta el filtro

```
  @Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ServiciosJwtUsuarios jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private final JwtToken jwtTokenUtil;

    public JwtRequestFilter(JwtToken jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String identifier = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                identifier = jwtTokenUtil.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (JWTDecodeException exception) {
                logger.error("No se pudo obtener el token JWT o el token JWT ha expirado", exception);
            }
        }
        if (identifier != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(identifier);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, identifier)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Traza del error

```
2023-03-29 17:11:48.024[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5184[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms




  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c3VhcmlvIjp7Im5vbWJyZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibGljZW5jaWEiOiJtMSJ9LCJleHAiOjE2ODAxODkwMjYsImlhdCI6MTY4MDEwMjYyNn0.Y_gpOM90tFdnpXQe8IWqyBk2t160LZFbklf1mc_yyt1e1EGTvJ-GtwUrwmY_83l0NQ-eKBQV4UpEi6oRRC9urA
    
    
    com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The input is not a valid base 64 encoded string.
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:46)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:444)
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.decodeToken(JwtToken.java:46)
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.getClaimFromToken(JwtToken.java:39)
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(JwtToken.java:31)
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:848)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:41)
    ... 60 more
[2m2023-03-29 23:40:14.758[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m17856[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/servidor] threw exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error decodificando el token
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.decodeToken(JwtToken.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.getClaimFromToken(JwtToken.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(JwtToken.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.7.jar:5.7.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The input is not a valid base 64 encoded string.
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:46) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:444) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    at com.proyecto.config.JwtToken.decodeToken(JwtToken.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:41) ~[java-jwt-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Parece un error del encoder (el token que recibe tu aplicación no es lo que estás enviando). Esto se podría ver mejor con un volcado de pila donde se vea el error y la cadena de llamadas. Además sería interesante que imprimas, en el filter, el valor de jwtToken antes de llamar a `obtenerIdentificadorDelToken`

Comment: Spring 4.7? Eso no existe. Y pues, resolviendo lo de la versión de spring, hay que ver si el algoritmo de cifrado es válido, está deprecado o no, etc. Incluye la traza completa del error tal y como hiciste en la pregunta del sitio en inglés

Comment: perdon fallo mio 2.7

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico ya tinee el log completo y el print en el filtro, los token tanto el que da el login como el qeu le paso como el que obtiene en el filtro yo los veo iguales

Comment: El print que hacés en consola, ¿te sale con las comillas? ¿Estás pasando las comillas como parte del token? Imprimí `jwtToken`, no `requestTokenHeader`.

Comment: se estaba pasando pero vamso da igual le he quitado las comillas y da el mismo error

Comment: Hm, el problema es que estás entregando el token con cosas de más (o de menos). Cómo, hay que averiguarlo. Para comenzar, es mala idea `requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")` para manipular el servletRequest, si lo que estás buscando es la cookie con el token...

Comment: @unknow, el token está bien formado. Una cosa que podés hacer es copiar y pegar el token (sin el bearer) en tu variable `jwtToken` y ver si decodifica eso. Si eso sucede entonces tu variable `jwtToken` contiene caracteres ajenos al token.

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico si meto el token sin el bearer en el postman en la linea del metodo getClaimFromToken
  return claimsResolver.apply(decodedJWT);
Devuelve nulo siendo el valor de decodedjWT
com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder@1c47461

Comment: @unknow, ponelo en Java, en el filtro, como valor hardode de `jwtToken`, una vez para probar (sin "Bearer "). Si eso funciona entonces tu problema es que el decoder no está recibiendo bien el valor. Para mí el problema es que estás pasando algún caracter de más, tal vez un espacio. Entonces `obtenerIdentificadorDelToken` está recibiendo un valor que es el token con algún caracter adicional.

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico el token es copiado y pegado no puede haber espacios perdidos, es mas tengo una app que hace peticiones a la api rest y tp rula. si en el postman le mando el token sin  (sin "Bearer ")
return claimsResolver.apply(decodedJWT); Devuelve nulo

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando Spring **Boot** 2.7. Spring es muchas cosas y el framework va en 5.3 ya (creo). Consejo: sé específico para recibir respuestas específicas.

Si estás usando JWT como corresponde, significa que debes estar entregando el token en una cookie con un nombre dado. Alguno, definido por ti. Así pues, en el servletRequest que interceptas con el filtro, tendrías que hacer algo como

```
private static final String COOKIE_NAME = "el-jwt";
String jwt = "";
String elToken = "";
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();

...
if (cookies != null) {
    jwt = Stream.of(cookies).filter(
            cookie -> COOKIE_NAME.equals(cookie.getName())
    ).map(
            Cookie::getValue
    ).findAny().orElse(null);
    
if (jwt != null && !jwt.trim().isEmpty()) {
    int positionWithout = jwt.lastIndexOf('.');
    elToken = jwt.substring(0, positionWithout + 1);
}

} else {
    // todo mal, no hay JWT en el request
}

System.out.println("EL token es: " + elToken);
```

Comment: Spring Boot va por la version 3 para java 17 o asi y 2.7.10 es la ultima version con fecha  Mar 23, 2023
La dependencia es >java-jwt 4.3.
Y no estoy miu puesto de como funciona pero el digo deberia fucnionar tal cual, eso de la ookie no tego ni dea

Comment: @unknow y bueno, dónde usas `doGenerateToken`?

Comment: en generarToken y se llama desde el controlador de AutenticacionController
    token = jwtToken.generarToken(optMedico.get());
  return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));